# Lookup table in R by matching ranges

Tags: r, lookup

I have a table:

```
CHR POS 
10  4342 
20  100
22  5422
```

I have another lookup:

```
CHR start end Gene
10  4000  5999 ABC1
20  50    200  JHT
22  5000  6000 KLO
```

Desired output:

```
CHR POS 
10  4342  ABC1
20  100   JHT
22  5422  KLO
```

In reality there are 700,000 entries in table 1 and roughly 60000 genes. I need to match on chromsome and then get the POS to be between start-end of table 2 to add a new column with the gene name.

I tried :

```
library(dplyr)

# create sample data
df1 <- data.frame(chromosome = c("chr1", "chr1", "chr2", "chr3"), position = c(100, 200, 300, 400))
df2 <- data.frame(chromosome = c("chr1", "chr2", "chr3"), start = c(50, 250, 350), end = c(150, 350, 450), gene = c("geneA", "geneB", "geneC"))

# perform left join
joined_df <- left_join(df1, df2, by = "chromosome")

# create new column indicating if each row lies within a gene
result_df <- joined_df %>%
              mutate(in_gene = if_else(position >= start & position <= end, gene, NA_character_))

# view result
result_df
```

But the vector was too large to store.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `GenomicRanges` for something like this. See commented out code at the beginning below for installing.

The `GRanges` class is a container for genomic locations and associated annotations.

The function `makeGRangesFromDataFrame` will take a data.frame as input and automatically find the columns that describe genomic ranges (default is `start` and `end` or `stop`).

Below uses the additional sample data provided.

```
# if (!require("BiocManager", quietly = TRUE))
#   install.packages("BiocManager")

# BiocManager::install("GenomicRanges")

library(GenomicRanges)

gr1 <- GRanges(seqnames = df1$chromosome,
               IRanges(start = df1$position, width = 1))
gr2 <- makeGRangesFromDataFrame(df2, keep.extra.columns = TRUE)

df1$gene <- NA
ovlp <- findOverlaps(gr1, gr2)
df1$gene[queryHits(ovlp)] <- gr2$gene[subjectHits(ovlp)]

df1
```

**Output**

```
  chromosome position  gene
1       chr1      100 geneA
2       chr1      200  <NA>
3       chr2      300 geneB
4       chr3      400 geneC
```

Answer (score 3):

With `dplyr` 1.1.0, we can use `join_by` for non-equi joins

```
library(dplyr)
left_join(df1, df2, by = join_by(CHR, 
    closest(POS >= start), closest(POS <= end))) %>%
   select(-start, -end)
```

-output

```
 CHR  POS Gene
1  10 4342 ABC1
2  20  100  JHT
3  22 5422  KLO
```

---

Or with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
 setDT(df1)[df2, Gene := i.Gene, on = .(CHR, POS >= start, POS <= end)]
```

-output

```
> df1
   CHR  POS Gene
1:  10 4342 ABC1
2:  20  100  JHT
3:  22 5422  KLO
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(CHR = c(10L, 20L, 22L), POS = c(4342L, 100L, 5422L
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))

df2 <- structure(list(CHR = c(10L, 20L, 22L), start = c(4000L, 50L, 
5000L), end = c(5999L, 200L, 6000L), Gene = c("ABC1", "JHT", 
"KLO")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a variation of left_join:

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>% 
  left_join(df2, by="CHR") %>% 
  filter(between(POS, start, end)) %>% 
  select(-c(start, end))

  CHR  POS Gene
1  10 4342 ABC1
2  20  100  JHT
3  22 5422  KLO
```

Answer (score 2):

Considering these tho guys,

```
m1
#   CHR  POS
# 1  10 4342
# 2  20  100
# 3  22 5422
# 4  11   10

m2
#   CHR start  end Gene
# 1  10  4000 5999 ABC1
# 2  20    50  200  JHT
# 3  22  5000 6000  KLO
# 4  11  5000 6000  KLO
```

you can do:

```
merge(m1, m2) |> {\(.) subset(., data.table::between(.$POS, .$start, .$end))}()
#   CHR  POS start  end Gene
# 1  10 4342  4000 5999 ABC1
# 2  20  100    50  200  JHT
# 3  22 5422  5000 6000  KLO
```

---

*Data:*

```
m1 <- structure(list(CHR = c(10L, 20L, 22L, 11L), POS = c(4342L, 100L, 
5422L, 10L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))


m2 <- structure(list(CHR = c(10L, 20L, 22L, 11L), start = c(4000L, 
50L, 5000L, 5000L), end = c(5999L, 200L, 6000L, 6000L), Gene = c("ABC1", 
"JHT", "KLO", "KLO")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```